# How does commutative and/or differential algebra think about total derivatives?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, soft-question, differential-algebra

If we apply the "operator" $\frac{d}{dx}$ to the polynomial $xy$, we get the expression $y+x\frac{dy}{dx}.$ (Source: high school.) Thinking of $xy$ as an element of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, it seems that $\frac{d}{dx}$ takes us into the "polynomial ring" $\mathbb{R}[x,y,\frac{dy}{dx}].$ We might write:

$$\frac{d}{dx} : \mathbb{R}[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x,y,\frac{dy}{dx}]$$

Perhaps this satisfies a universal property that explains why it feels like a natural thing to do. Anyway:

> **Question.** Broadly speaking, how does commutative and/or differential algebra think about total derivatives, and from which book (article, etc.) can I learn this way of thinking?

[Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400227/understanding-implicit-differentiation-with-concepts-like-function-and-lambda)

Comment: What you might want to read about are differential forms and the tangent space as the set of derivations.

Comment: Since $dy/dx$ is not just zero for you there must be some relationship between $y$ and $x$ that has not been clarified. You probably know that commutative algebra constructs a module of differentials for any map of commutative rings. Here if, say, the ring is $A = k[x,y]/(f(x,y))$ then relative to $k$ we get an $A$-module generated by two symbols $dx$ and $dy$ with the the relation $(\partial_xf)dx + (\partial_yf)dy$. The details of the construction and the universal property it satisfies are all spelled out in Chapter 16 of Eisenbud's “Commutative Algebra”.

Comment: @Hoot, from an algebraic viewpoint, for $dy/dx$ to not be zero, what we really need to do is *refrain* from giving a relationship between $x$ and $y$, and then state a universal property.